# Tanpura app during Bansuri Practice

Tags: woodwinds, indian-classical, bansuri, tanpura

I am viewing this tutorial

and am unclear on

Please clarify two things

What is purpose of Tanpura (I got Tanpura Droid) playing in background. Is it to create an ambiance which practising, or is it much more?

How do I set Tanpura. I set the pitch to A-scale, since I have an A-scale flute, but what do I set first string?

Do I keep it at `Sa`, **or** do I change it every time I am going from one scale to the other, i.e. I start practice by doing 5 deep blows of `Sa`, 5 of `Re`, 5 of `Ga` .. `Ma`, `PA`, `DHA`, `NI`, `SA`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One plays the *tanpura* in the background to help
fix the pitch of your playing. Since you have a flute
that is set to the A-scale, set the tanpura to the pitch
A. Set the first string to Pa.

The reason for choosing Sa and Pa to be played on the tanpura
is that these notes are "fixed" in all *ragas*, so having
a constant drone playing these notes in the background gives
you a base which you can rely on to fix your pitch while
playing the flute.

I might add that [@Rusi is not incorrect in saying](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/80347/38256) that what
note is played on the first string of the tanpura depends
on the raga being played. However, it is enough to keep
this as a general rule as a beginner that the tanpura
is set to the pitch you are playing and that the first string
is set to Pa.

Do not change the tuning of the tanpura as per the notes you
are playing: that would defeat the purpose of having the tanpura.
The tanpura is not an accompaniment to your music, in the sense
that it does not follow the notes you play. It stays constant
in the background to provide a base for your playing. Use the
Sa and Pa played on the tanpura to understand the positions of
the remaining notes (Re, Ga, Ma, Dha, Ni) as well, in relation
to Sa and Pa.

This is the primary function of the tanpura. However, I do not
deny that playing the tanpura also lends a pleasant ambience.

Comment: Very comprehensive explanation ..... `gives you a base which you can rely on to fix your pitch while playing the flute.` Does this includes notes playing at higher octaves?

Comment: @Marium Yes, this includes playing notes at higher octaves as well.

Answer (score 4):

In Indian classical the tanpura never changes (or should not).

A teacher of mine reminded me:

> How utterly opposite are the words tanpura and it's supposed
>   translation : drone
>
> Drone signifies  boredom, monotony
>
> Tan-pura literally means infinite fullness of sound

---

The first string depends on rag but is usually the fifth